# How do I add a previously removed physical volume back to a volume group?

Tags: lvm

After removing a physical volume from a machine, and returning the physical volume back to the machine, the physical volume is ignored and the following message appears:

```
[root@emma ~]# pvscan
  WARNING: VG vg001 was previously updated while PV /dev/sdc was missing.
  WARNING: VG vg001 was missing PV /dev/sdc HeNyWe-Efmc-Lb0R-L8w5-nVp7-aPSs-Ntbs0Z.
```

How do I add the physical volume back to the volume group?

Answer (score 1):

To add the physical volume back to the logical volume, run `vgextend --restoremissing` as follows.

```
[root@emma ~]# vgextend --restoremissing vg001 /dev/sdc
  WARNING: VG vg001 was previously updated while PV /dev/sdc was missing.
  WARNING: VG vg001 was missing PV /dev/sdc HeNyWe-Efmc-Lb0R-L8w5-nVp7-aPSs-Ntbs0Z.
  WARNING: VG vg001 was previously updated while PV /dev/sdc was missing.
  Volume group "vg001" successfully extended
```

Source: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1741276